# ¿Cómo obtener el nombre del idioma establecido en Android?

Tags: java, android

Con el siguiente código Java cambio el idioma de mi aplicación:

```
public class Utils {

    private static Locale defaultLocale;

    public static void setLocale(Context myContext, String languageToLoad) {

        if (defaultLocale == null) defaultLocale = Locale.getDefault(); //backup default locale

        if (languageToLoad.equals("default")) languageToLoad = defaultLocale.getLanguage();
        Log.d("UsefulFunctions", "setLocale():" + languageToLoad);

        Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.locale = locale;
        myContext.getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
                myContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

    }
}
```

Quiero añadir una función `getDisplayLanguage` para que me devuelve el idioma establecido, no su identificador(`es`, `en`), es decir si defino el idioma como: `es` que me devuelva `español`

Para obtener los idiomas disponibles que hay en Android

```
Locale locales[] = Locale.getAvailableLocales();
```

[Ver tabla how-do-i-display-all-available-locales.html (en)](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-display-all-available-locales.html)

Para obtener el nombre de un idioma de la lista

```
locale[i].getDisplayLanguage()
```

Solo necesito cómo buscar dentro del array de tipo `Locale` un idioma especifico, pasando un parámetro tipo `Language` es decir `es`

**Ejemplo del Resultado:**

```
Utils.setLoclae('es');
Utils.getDisplayLanguage('es') //devuelve Español
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Prueba como primera opción:

```
Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage();
```

también

```
Locale.getDefault().getDisplayName();
```

Comment: Pues si funciona, no ser para que me complicaba la vida

Comment: Que se obtiene con  getDisplayName(), lo has probado???

Comment: @Elenasys Ese no pero según la documentación es un resultado similar [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html#getDisplayName())

Comment: Solo conocia como opción getDisplayLanguage() , pero revisando la documentación usando Locale.getDefault().getDisplayName(); sin definir un Locale, devuelbe por ejemplo "Español", lo cual también es correcto! =)

Comment: @Elenasys si lo he probado, me devuelve el nombre del idioma sin el pais entre paréntesis.

Comment: Si @Webserveis también lo acabo de probar porque de hecho sinceramente desconocía esta otra opción, lo que hiciste .getDisplayName() es similar a new Locale("es").getDisplayName() y obtiene "Español"

Comment: @Elenasys en el enlace que he puesto en la pregunta hay los valores, tal cual cómo se obtienen de cada método, http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-display-all-available-locales.html

Comment: Muchas gracias por la información, es un articulo muy bueno.

Answer (score 2):

Se usa [**`getDisplayLanguage()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html#getDisplayLanguage()) :

```
Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage();
```

> **`getDisplayLanguage()`** Devuelve el nombre del lenguaje local.

<sup>—————</sup>

Revisando el uso de **[getDisplayName()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html#getDisplayName())**, se puede considerar como otra opción aunque devuelve datos más específicos como son nombre, nombre del país, y la variante, como se puede ver en los ejemplos de la documentación:

- `new Locale("en").getDisplayName(Locale.US)`

  obtiene: **`English`**
- `new Locale("en", "US").getDisplayName(Locale.US)`

  obtiene: **`English (United States)`**
- `new Locale("en", "US", "POSIX").getDisplayName(Locale.US)`

  obtiene: **`English (United States,Computer)`**
- `Locale.fromLanguageTag("zh-Hant-CN").getDisplayName(Locale.US)`

  obtiene: **`Chinese (Traditional Han,China)`**
- `new Locale("en").getDisplayName(Locale.FRANCE)`

  obtiene: **`anglais`**
- `new Locale("en", "US").getDisplayName(Locale.FRANCE)`

  obtiene: **`anglais (États-Unis)`**
- `new Locale("en", "US", "POSIX").getDisplayName(Locale.FRANCE)`

  obtiene: **`anglais (États-Unis,informatique)`**.

En [este artículo](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-display-all-available-locales.html) que comparte @Webserveis podemos ver los valores obtenidos a partir del Locale con `getDisplayLanguage()` y con `getDisplayName()`:

Comment: Es la misma respuesta que está arriba :/

Comment: Especifica el uso de getDisplayName() ya que no regresa únicamente "el nombre del idioma establecido"